# Extract row number from a formula into another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

is there a good way to do this? I'm using `MID` and `Formulatext` to extract the row number to another cell from a formula.

The issue is the results are not consistent as some rows are single, double, or triple digits and MID will not work.

Example Below.

Formula (A1):

```
=SUMIFS('Customer'!17:17,'Customer'!1:1,Forecast!AM1)
```

Formula (B1)

```
=MID(FORMULATEXT(AM4),23,5)
```

Result = `17:17`

Comment: `=TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(FORMULATEXT(AM4),","),"!")`

Comment: Thank you Scott, that's exactly the approach I was researching before you answered, I appreciate your help. You solved the case!